# How to play a video in real time using python Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am wanting to play a video at its correct speed. When I play the current video it is very slow. The faster the frame rate of the video I play the slower it goes. I was wondering if there is a way to get the frame rate and based on the fps it will play it at the correct speed. Below is the code I have so far.

Another question: When I play the video it appears grainy, is that due to the video currently not playing at the correct speed or due to the inefficiency of the code?

Thanks for the help, it is much appreciated.

```
def openVideo():

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('./track.mp4')
    
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

openVideo()
```

Comment: Try decreasing the resolution of the video.

Comment: your code run pretty good on my side, can you try run other video format instead? like .avi

Comment: use some better/faster video rendering sdk, openCV GUI isn't designed for programming real applications, it's more for debugging purposes and simple tasks.